# Use objects as dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d` which stores some information about objects:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a = A(1)
b = A(1)
c = 'hello world'
e = [1, 2, 3]

d = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', e: 'e'}
```

Two questions arise:

1. The approach does not work for lists or for other objects whose hash does not correspond to the storage address. What can I do in that cases?
2. Is that approach unsafe under other conditions than mentioned in question (1)?

Comment: What is the point of having a dictionary whose keys are the value? It would only be supported if the object is hashable (has __hash__ defined). What's wrong with using a list or a set?

Comment: So you are trying to use objects as keys in the dictionary.  I don't understand this motivation.

Comment: Must you have the objects as keys of the dictionary? Can't you do something like keep the object in a separate list and use the indexes of that list as keys?

Comment: The question is rather academic, and I'm hoping for answers to clarify the question, not for solutions with a similar effect :-)

Answer (score 2):

To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the `hash` function (e.g. through `__hash__`), equality comparison (e.g. through `__eq__` or `__cmp__`), and must satisfy the correctness condition above.

That said, the simple answer to why lists cannot be used as dictionary keys is that **lists do not provide a valid `__hash__` method.**

Please refer [*Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys?*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) for detailed information.

But you can use [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) object instead as `key` as tuples are hashable. Hence, it is valid to do:

```
>>> e = (1, 2, 3)
>>> d = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', e: 'e'}
```